# Create a file list in IICS informatica and load the files to a table

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, iics

I want to load a bunch of files with the same structure and same name format(ABCD_MMYYDD) every month from local folder to Snowflake table. The server we  use is a windows server. So I wanted to know how can configure iics so that similar filenames are picked up and loaded. Currently we use filewatcher to create a file list and then use that to load the files.Do we have any other alternatives to this?

Comment: Hi - why are looking for an alternative to a solution that already works?

Comment: I was previously working with SSMS and there i could easily load the files from folder to the DB.So when IICS came into picture,which i am learning now,i couldnot find any easy method like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

- run the process on schedule (e.g. every 8 hours), process would start by running a script that prepares a list of available files and load all of them and archive the files after loading. This is an alternative. Pros: no file listener needed. Cons: it runs on a fixed schedule, files are not loaded as-they-come
- keep using the filewatcher as you are. Pros: files loaded right after arrival. Cons: filewatcher, multiple process spawned.